# Is there an efficient way to pass a delegate argument? Or better yet to "inline" the function using the delegate

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on some code that can wrap error handling logic to avoid cluttering methods, which looks something like this:

```
public static B? Handle<A,B>(this A a, Func<A,B> func){
    try{
        return func(a);
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
Foo a = new();
a.Handle(x => new Bar(x));
```

Of course there are many reasons not to do the above specifically but it is just an example. The performance of it is not great because the function that is passed in gets allocated, particularly if the function uses variables from the external scope.

Since this code is technically just a "macro" to make the error handling neater, is there a way to achieve nearly the equivalent performance of writing the try-catch directly without a helper method?

I suppose one option could be to use Source Generators to expand it out, but there are issues with that too, particularly in terms of debugging and how pervasive the 'handle' function would be in the relevant codebase.

Comment: Depending on your compiler version, maybe a [function pointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#function-pointers) might help? *(You'd obviously need to measure the performance before and after to see if there was an improvement.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody). It allows executing code at the beginning, end or on exception by simply adding an attribute to the method.

Here is an example for catching the exception and returning some value:

```
public sealed class ReturnOneOnExceptionAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
  public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
  {
    args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
    args.ReturnValue = 1;
  }
}

class Program
{
  [ReturnOneOnException]
  static object x()
  {
    throw new Exception();
    Console.WriteLine("in x");
  }

  static void Main()
  {
    var a = x();
    Console.WriteLine(a);
  }
}
```

As mentiond by `Richard Deeming` in the comment, make sure to measure the difference in performance rather than going by what looks faster.

Comment: Hmm, this implies that the called object needs to handle the exception which may not be true all the time. Additionally, from what I understand, we wouldn't be able to breakpoint the code in this case? Or am I mistaken about that?

Comment: The `FlowBehavior` allows returning, rethrowing or continuing.